# Matlab script for creating and exporting plots

Tags: matlab, plot, export

I have in Simulink a Scope with multiplexor block Mux (i want to draw multiples wavaforms in one graph). After simulation i need to export it in defined form (background color, lines width, etc.) to eps/pdf and png files.

**Actual problem:**

- colors in legend are incorrect.

**My dream**:

- start simulation in Simulink (click F5 to start)
- then call my own function (script) to export it (e.g. *set_and_export(label x, label y, legend wave 1, legend wave 2, .. ,legend wave x)*)

The final state is to fulfill my dream.

My m file:

```
% Get the data from Simulink
% First column is the time signal
% in Scope in Simulink : Array with time
[nothing, NumOfSgns] = size(ScopeData)
time = ScopeData(:,1);

% Plot all signals
hold on
for j=0:NumOfSgns-2,
    graph=plot(time,ScopeData(:,2+j:end),'Color', rand(1,3));

    % Signals description and position of the legend
    legend('firs wave form','next wave form','Location','SouthEast');
end
hold off
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: In my script is a mistake in creating graph (somewhere around/in the for loop 'Plot all signals'). It runs well for one waveform (If instead of a for loop I use only 'graph=plot(time,ScopeData(:,2:end)').

Comment: Please try to isolate the code that shows the problem. See http://sscce.org.

Comment: I simplified the first post.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your problem is most likely that you've put the call to legend in the loop, which will clear the legend and replace it with the new one at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I moved the line with legend behind the loop (and before hold off). No improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using both `legend` and `hold on`: Because you use `hold on`, MATLAB doesn't clear the old plot before drawing the new. But it doesn't store the previous plots' information for `legend`. You need to do this manually.

Here's some code (untested, don't have access to MATLAB at the moment):

```
titles = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
handles = zeros(1, length(titles));
figure;
hold on;
for i = 1 : length(titles)
    handles(i) = plot(1 : 10, rand(1, 10), 'Color', rand(1, 3));
end
legend(handles, titles{:});
```

So: Store the handles returned by `plot` in a vector and pass it to `legend` (which you need to call after the loop).

Comment: It plots graph with legend fine but I it does not show labels for axis. Under your code I added xlabel('xxx','FontSize',15); ylabel('yyy','FontSize',15) and nothing is displayed. Any ideas where is problem?

Comment: @user1313386: Adding your label code below my code works fine for me on MATLAB R2012b, I get both the intended x- and y-axis labels.

Comment: After rebooting my computer is everything ok. Thank you very much to all who contributed to the discussion.